# Escape commas when writing string to CSV

Tags: python, csv, escaping, prepend

I need to prepend a comma-containing string to a CSV file using Python. Some say enclosing the string in double quotes escapes the commas within. This does not work. How do I write this string without the commas being recognized as seperators?

```
string = "WORD;WORD 45,90;WORD 45,90;END;"
with open('doc.csv') as f:
    prepended = string + '\n' + f.read()
with open('doc.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(prepended)
```

Comment: I would use module `csv` but you can use `" "` inside `' '` - `string = 'WORD;"WORD 45,90";"WORD 45,90";END;'`

Answer (score 1):

So as you point out, you can typically quote the string as below. Is the system that reads these files not recognizing that syntax? If you use python's `csv` module it will handle the proper escaping:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(myIterable, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

The quoted strings would look like:

```
"string1","string 2, with, commas"
```

Note if you have a quote character within your string it will be written as `""` (two quote chars in a row):

```
"string1","string 2, with, commas, and "" a quote"
```